# Converting PDF (generated using pdflatex) to LaTeX

Tags: pdf, text-processing, latex

Is there a package which converts PDF to LaTeX? I have the PDFs created using TeX but I have lost the original `.tex` file.

Can I retrieve the TeX back from PDF?

Comment: Do you have a pdf with equations or a pdf with pure text?

Comment: Answered at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. Most of the information used to generate the PDF is lost during its creation and only the result is retained (unless you told the TeX processor to attach the source files to the result document).

Answer (score 0):

On the tex stackexchange page you can find this [discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex).

A short answer to your question: **No**.

But there are some tools which can help you to make a tex from  a pdf.

- Use the writer2latex plugin in [LibreOffice](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/writer2latex-1)
- The command line version can be found on the [Writer2Latex page](http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net).
- If you have a lots of mathematics in it, try [InftyReader](http://www.inftyreader.org/).
- If you have a pure text document you can simply convert the text to a `*.txt`file by

  ```
  pdftotext myDocument.pdf MyDocument.txt
  ```

  and make a new latex document from it.